# DateTime() and IntlDateFormatter diffrent hours when convert timezone

Tags: php, datetime, php-8.1, intldateformatter

Example:

```
$date = new DateTime('2023-09-08 06:00:00.0', new DateTimeZone('UTC')); // USER's timezone

echo $date->format('Y-m-d H:i:s');

$formatter = new IntlDateFormatter(
    'en', 
    IntlDateFormatter::SHORT, 
    IntlDateFormatter::SHORT, 
    'CST', 
    IntlDateFormatter::GREGORIAN,
    'YYYY-MM-dd HH:mm'
);
echo '</br>';
echo $formatter->format($date );

echo '</br>';
$date->setTimezone(new DateTimeZone('CST'));
echo $date->format('Y-m-d H:i:s');
```

output:

2023-09-08 06:00:00

2023-09-08 01:00

2023-09-08 00:00:00

why results is diffrent, which one is correct?

Comment: You echo the date 3 times in the code, why are there only 2 dates in the output?

Comment: Both kinda are correct. CST is -6, but the current timezone is CDT (until Nov 5th), which is -5.

Comment: @aynber does DateTime not know how to determine summer time?

Comment: It would if you used a location timezone instead of CDT/CST, which specifies the exact offset. So try `America/Chicago`, which is solidly in the US Central timezone.

Comment: I would strongly suggest reading the notes at the top of https://www.php.net/manual/en/timezones.others.php

Comment: CST is UTC-6 so the correct local time is 0:00. But some territories switch to CDT (UTC-5) from 12 March 2023 to 5 November 2023, so local time would be 1:00. DateTime::format() is definitively right (but not useful, you need to specify the exact region as already said). I've no idea why IntlDateFormatter prints CDT time when instructed to use CST.

Comment: Interestingly, IntlDateFormatter does not accept CDT as time zone. So I guess that ICU timezone database handles DST differently.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In the pattern you've provided to `IntlDateFormatter`, you're using '`YYYY`' which represents the "week year". You should use '`yyyy`' for the calendar year.

```
$date = new DateTime('2023-09-08 06:00:00.0', new DateTimeZone('UTC')); // USER's timezone

echo $date->format('Y-m-d H:i:s');

$formatter = new IntlDateFormatter(
    'en', 
    IntlDateFormatter::SHORT, 
    IntlDateFormatter::SHORT, 
    'America/Chicago', // Use a full time zone identifier
    IntlDateFormatter::GREGORIAN,
    'yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm' // Use 'yyyy' instead of 'YYYY'
);
echo '</br>';
echo $formatter->format($date );

echo '</br>';
$date->setTimezone(new DateTimeZone('America/Chicago')); 
echo $date->format('Y-m-d H:i:s');
```